# Laravel - Access relations property

Tags: arrays, laravel, nested

I need to access at the email value; it become from a relation hasOnce(),
this is dd($this->order_details)

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2322 ▼   #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => App\Order {#2327 ▼
      #hidden: array:1 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "orders"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:12 [▶]
      #original: array:12 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: array:1 [▶]
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "user" => App\User {#2356 ▼
          #dispatchesEvents: array:1 [▶]
          #fillable: array:3 [▶]
          #hidden: array:9 [▶]
          #casts: array:1 [▶]
          #connection: "mysql"
          #table: "users"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:20 [▼
            "id" => 36
            "email" => "email@gmail.com"
            "password" => "$2y$10$f.u7MO6ZZ4GBf1uaabiF9OXerh0SR7JzUV9M5PGI1IG1xFATkeTSG"
            "name" => "NAME"
            "surname" => "SURNAME"
            "phone" => "+39331199222"
            "confirm_code" => 111111
            "confirm_code_date" => "2020-06-01 18:17:42"
            "confirm_tries" => 0
            "city_id" => 5662
            "stripe_customer_id" => "cus_HPVN1YJE0wjHtm"
            "status" => "ACTIVE"
            "is_admin" => 1
            "price_list_id" => 1
            "wallet" => 99852.6
            "last_login_at" => "2020-06-05 11:49:32"
            "remember_token" => null
            "created_at" => "2020-06-01 18:17:42"
            "updated_at" => "2020-06-08 16:33:12"
            "deleted_at" => null
```

when i try to get it with: `$this->order_details->user->email` 
i get back:

> Property [user] does not exist on this collection instance.

I've no idea which is my error and what is wrong to get it as well, 
with `$this->order_details->user[0]->email` 
the result is the same

Comment: `$this->order_details` is returning a `Collection`, and not an `Order` instance, so you can't access `->user`. If you expect that `order_details` should only return a single `Order`, you'll need to modify your `order_details` method to only return a single `hasOne()` or `belongsTo()`. Update your question to include your relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access an object which is not present in the collection.

`$this->order_details` is a `Collection`

You need to access the first `order`, before you can access the `user`:

```
$firstOrder = $this->order_details->first();

$user = $firstOrder->user;

$email = $user->email;

// Or:
$email = $this->order_details->first()->user->email;
```

Of course you can also iterate over the orders in the collection, but for now I assumed you only need the first order.